# Mongodb sharding, replicate collection on all shards

Tags: mongodb, collections, replication, sharding

I have a mongodb sharded cluster and would like to know if it's possible to force a collection to be copied on all shards.
I think it could be an unsharded collection on a primary shard, but with an option to replicate it to all shards in case of hardware issue.

For example if I have 3 shards, I would like the data of a certain collection accessible even if 2 shards are offline.

Thanks for you help

Comment: Each shard must be a Replica Set. Unless you run a replica set with just a single node, the data is replicated. What else do you need?

Comment: In case of an issue of the 2 instances of the replica set, the shard is down. I want to prevent this by copying data on all shards

Comment: Then create a 6-member replica set instead of a sharded cluster. Or, if you prefer a simple answer: No, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of sharding is to distribute data over multiple mongod instances because there is too much data for all of it to be on the same instance.

Duplicating data on multiple shards is counter to this purpose.

If you want redundancy and all of your data fits into one database instance (i.e. on one server), use a single replica set and add as many nodes as you want for your desired redundancy level.